# How to word question to indicate default answer in console application?

Tags: console, console-application

How to word question to indicate default answer in console application?

- Coca-Cola size [] Medium [S] Small [L] Large
- Coca-Cola size [Enter] Medium [S] Small [L] Large
- Coca-Cola size [Medium] [S] Small [L] Large

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the way certain Linux stuff does it:

```
Allow non-root access (Y/N) [default=N]: _
```

For your specific use case, you could do:

```
Coca-Cola size (M)edium, (S)mall or (L)arge [default=M]: _
```